# How to represent a form-data request using Akka HTTP?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I want to create a form-data http request to [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads) using Akka HTTP. In curl, the request example looks like:

```
curl \
 -X POST \
 "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/1533641336884006/videos"  \
 -F "access_token=XXXXXXX" \
 -F "upload_phase=transfer" \
 -F "start_offset=0" \
 -F "upload_session_id=1564747013773438" \
 -F "video_file_chunk=@chunk1.mp4"
```

So I created a following model for a request payload representation:

```
case class FBSingleChunkUpload(accessToken: String, 
    sessionId: String,
    from: Long, 
    to: Long, 
    file: File) //file is always ~1Mb
```

Then I'm going to use:

```
Http().cachedHostConnectionPoolHttps[String]("graph-video.facebook.com")
```

But I don't know how to convert `FBSingleChunkUpload` to the correct `HttpRequest` :(

Can you give me a hint, how to represent a such type of requests using Akka HTTP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an `FormData` `Entity` type for that

```
 val fBSingleChunkUpload = ???
 HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST,
              entity = FormData(("accessToken", fBSingleChunkUpload.accessToken), ...).toEntity)
```

Additionally for the file you could check if it works with `Multipart.FormData`

```
 val fileFormPart = Multipart.FormData
    .BodyPart("name", HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`, file.length(), FileIO.fromPath(file.toPath)))

  val otherPart = Multipart.FormData.BodyPart.Strict("accessToken", "the token")

  val entity =
    Multipart.FormData(otherPart, fileFormPart).toEntity
```

Comment: Regarding the text fields it's clear. What about the file field?

Comment: I updated the example, please check if that leads you to the solution for you :)

Answer (score 3):

In curl, the `-F` option stipulates a POST using the "multipart/form-data" content type. To create such a request in Akka HTTP, use [`Multipart.FormData`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/10.1.1/akka/http/scaladsl/model/Multipart$$FormData$.html) (`defaultEntity` below is borrowed from Akka HTTP's [`MultipartSpec`](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/blob/v10.1.1/akka-http-core/src/test/scala/akka/http/scaladsl/model/MultipartSpec.scala#L75)):

```
val chunkUpload = FBSingleChunkUpload(...)

def defaultEntity(content: String) =
  HttpEntity.Default(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, content.length, Source(ByteString(content) :: Nil))

val streamed = Multipart.FormData(Source(
  Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("access_token", defaultEntity(chunkUpload.accessToken)) ::
  Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("upload_phase", defaultEntity("transfer")) ::
  Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("start_offset", defaultEntity(chunkUpload.from.toString)) ::
  Multipart.FormData.BodyPart("upload_session_id", defaultEntity(chunkUpload.sessionId)) ::
  Multipart.FormData.BodyPart.fromFile(
    "video_file_chunk", ContentType.Binary(MediaTypes.`video/mp4`), chunkUpload.file
  ) :: Nil))

val request =
  HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = /** your URI */, entity = streamed.toEntity)
```

Comment: would you recommend to change `File` to `Array[Byte]`? In one of previous stages before I send the request to Facebook, I read an `InputStream` and create a `File`. But I'm curious does it better / easier to create the same type of `HttpRequest` but with `Array[Byte]` instead of `File`? Thanks